# Convert and manipulate a list of strings into a string (with extra characters)

Tags: python

Using Python, I would like to convert a list to string looks like this:
I'm looking for a more elegant way then loops

```
cmd = ['cd ..', 'pwd', 'howami']

"cd..; pwd; howami"
```

Thanks in advance (it is my first question BTW, please be gentle)

Roy

```
for cmdStr in cmd:     
   cmdString += cmdStr + '; '

cmdString.rstrip('; ')
```

Comment: You need [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). For example: `"; ".join(cmd)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `join` function.

```
"; ".join(cmd)
```

output

```
cd ..; pwd; howami
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is `join`.
In your example it would look like this:

```py
cmd = ['cd ..', 'pwd', 'howami']

"; ".join(cmd)
```

More on join in python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 0):

Different ways you can use

Using functools.reduce method

```
from functools import reduce
cmd = ['cd ..', 'pwd', 'howami']
string = reduce(lambda a, b : a+ "; " +str(b), cmd)
print(string)
```

Using enumerate function

```
cmd = ['cd ..', 'pwd', 'howami']
string = '; '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(cmd)])
print(string)
```

Using map()

```
cmd = ['cd ..', 'pwd', 'howami']

string =  '; '.join(map(str, cmd))
print(string)
```

Comment: Using enumerate is not necessary as you are not accessing index anywhere. Ensuring that input is list of strings is fine tho.

The option with functools isn't more "elegant" as op mentioned, it adds another import, use lambda function, which makes it less readable.

Comment: yeah you are correct about it .i just showed another ways you can use or you can implement it